# viewing LIVE drawing on CANVAS for multiple users

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, canvas

I am creating interactive network diagram on canvas where users can drag and drop, etc.
Things are drawn on the canvas with javascript. And on submit, data on the canvas will be sent via POST to php and mysql

What's the strategy to allow other users to see LIVE what I've on my canvas as I modifying them LIVE?
I don't know if it's a good idea to use AJAX because then you would be constantly messing with the DB even before you finalize it.

I'm not asking for specific code, just big picture STRATEGY, potential LIBRARY to use, DIRECTION.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this live you have about 3 options.

Comet http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Ajax Polling http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29 
(Make your ajax call every minute, seconds or whatever, there are obvious downsides to do it more quickly.)

Websockets (very experimental but now working in FF5 again) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websockets

Also you want to seriously think about storing the data that's going to be accessed in memory instead of a db so that every time a request is made or pushed or whatever method you are going to use, it doesn't hit the database everytime.  Use a database for permanent storage only, not for data that will be accessed every second.

Comment: What do you mean "accessed in memory", how would data of the canvas be transferred from one computer to another?

Comment: You can make a MySQL table use the "MEMORY" storage engine and it will be stored in RAM. I've used that for user ping times in an AJAX chat app, and it works quite well.

Comment: "In memory" refers to how the temporary drawings are stored on the server - you really don't want to make the server write to the hard disk every time a line is drawn. (Edit: I don't know why, but "memory" usually means RAM in these contexts.)

Comment: I should have been more specific but nkorth is right.  Every time you do an insert on the database you are writing to the disk.  Every time you do a select statement without some sort of caching mechanism you are reading from the disk and in this case caching would not be good for live data.  A temporary table is a good solution among many solutions, because it is stored in RAM.

Comment: I just reread your question William.  You ask how data of the canvas is transferred from one computer to another.  You need to understand the nature of the client and server relationship.  The server keeps all the necessary data.  Through the various means I posted the client is able to get the information from the server and send updates to the server.  Comet implements a type of push technology where data is pushed to the client.  Ajax polling is a method where the client is constantly asking the server for the latest information.